# pass ArrayList from android module to core in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx. I need to pass ArrayList of TaskSet from android to core. The problem is TaskSet is located in android module. I can pass some standard objects like Strings this way:

```
public class DragAndDropTest extends ApplicationAdapter {
......
    public DragAndDropTest(String value){
        this.value=value;
    }
......
}
```

In AndroidLauncher:

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
                LinearLayout lg=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.game);
                lg.addView(initializeForView(new DragAndDropTest("Some String"), config));
```

It's working fine, but i need to pass ArrayList of TaskSet, TaskSet is in android module

I know the bad solution is to place TaskSet to the "core" module, but anyway i need some methods to interract wigh android part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this in the way you're asking for, you won't be able to maintain multi-platform functionality. Which also means you won't be able to test on desktop. That will cost you a lot of time compiling and loading Android APK's onto devices.

But you should be able to do it by cutting and pasting all the stuff from the `android` block to the `core` block in your project's `build.gradle` file. It would look like this:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"        
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

But like I said, that's probably not what you want to do. I suggest using an interface such that all your code that handles the TaskSets stays in the Android module. Something like this:

```
public interface PlatformResolver {
    public void handleTasks();
}
```

-

```
public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    //......

    PlatformResolver platformResolver;

    public MyGame (PlatformResolver platformResolver){
        this.platformResolver = platformResolver;
    }

    //.....
    public void render(){
        //...

        if (shouldHandleTasks) platformResolver.handleTasks();

        //...
}
```

-

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements PlatformResolver {

    public void handleTasks(){
        //Do stuff with TaskSets
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        someDataType SomeData;

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        // config stuff
        initialize(new MyGame(this), config);
    }

}
```

-

```
public class DesktopLauncher  implements PlatformResolver{

    public void handleTasks(){
        Gdx.app.log("Desktop", "Would handle tasks now.");
    } 

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "My GDX Game";
        config.width = 480;
        config.height = 800;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(this), config);
    }
}
```